# Learning about probabilities

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Assume that there is a raffle that randomly selects a number from `0 to 9`.

You can choose a single number to place a `$1` and gain `$5` if you win.

You can choose as many numbers as you want.

**Which is the best strategy to maximize the possibility of making money?**

I feel that the best shot that you have is to pick 4 different numbers, which will land you a `4/10` probability of wining `$1`. But I can't help it feel that it seems a bit simplistic. Truth is, I know little about probability.

Though I might as well come in and ask, because it really peeked my interest. Is there maybe another possibility with better odds? maybe pick one number `N` times, another one `M` times, and yet another `X` times?, or any other approach maybe?

Seemed interesting to me, and since my probability knowledge is basic at best, I am also thinking of variants as *"what would happen if the payout differ for a specific number?"*, or what would happen if "*there was a second raffle with only the remaining 9 numbers?"*, *"how did they calculated that a `1 to 5` pay out would help the house odds?"*, *"is there another payment that works?"*, *"what would be a bad pay out for the house?"* and a whole lot of similar general questions, however not sure what to read to learn about it, will love any suggestion.

Comment: Suppose you put one dollar on the number zero. Assuming all numbers are equally likely, the probability of zero being picked in the raffle is $1/10=0.1$. Therefore, the expected value of the game is
$$
0.1\times5-1=0.5-1=-0.5
$$In expectation, you lose fifty cents by placing a bet on zero. Since
there was nothing special about the number zero, this is true for
any choice. The optimal strategy is to not play at all.

Comment: I see... So, if the pay out was something like 11 for every 1 betted, the expectation would become positive, and that's the point were betting for all the numbers would guarantee a winning! This is amazing! Would have love to learn about it in school.

Comment: "*pick 4 different numbers which will land you a 4/10 probability of winning 1*" and a 6/10 probability of having "won" negative 4 (*i.e. spent and lost 4 dollars*)... Continuing the calculation, $\frac{4}{10}\times 1 + \frac{6}{10}\times (-4) = -2$ so the expected result for betting four times is that you will have just lost $2$ dollars... far worse than the optimal strategy which was alluded to before of not betting anything at all.

Comment: Read more about [Expected Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) on wikipedia or in any introductory probability or statistics textbook.